# Creating A Java Document Design Editor

Tags: java, swing, editor

I am working on creating an editor as part of a lager JAVA application that would allow the user to drag and drop different custom Swing components onto a panel (just like a GUI editor). I also want to have the user able to rotate these objects by the mouse. I have been looking at JXLayer and TransformUI, but I don't want to add a whole bunch of libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: I thought my question was pretty specific. Perhaps you can help me ask it better. I want to basically create a GUI editor styled editor in my JAVA app and I'd rather not invent the wheel for scratch if there is a API/library that would help me. Searching for this is hard because I don't want a GUI editor to do JAVA development, but rather a GUI editor made in JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider to build your application on top of the NetBeans Platform (a Swing based RCP) and use its Visual Library:

http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/

Comment: Thanks, this is also close to what I am looking for. Just to put it out there, you don't need to use netBeans to use the Visual Library API.

Comment: I thought so, too, but couldn't find that statement anymore.

Comment: Now that you got me pointed down the right track, I want to mention I found GEF in the Eclipse project too. I think the netBeans API looks better so far.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a customizer framework for such tasks: Move and resize components with the mouse and allow further customizations. "Snap-to-grid"-feature included! Maybe you find it useful. (It's open source!)

I started to write a tutorial (still under construction!):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/customizer/index.html

For adding components see:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/CustomizerBar.html

To customize properties use:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JCustomizerPropertyTable.html

Register it to the SelectionManager of the JCustomizerPane and set the CustomizableProperties-property of the JCustomizer objects.

Also have a look at the subclasses of JCustomizer.

E.g. there are

customizers for images & shapes:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JXIconCustomizer.html

a label customizer with inline editing:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLabelCustomizer.html

a line customizer:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLine2DCustomizer.html

And there are many classes providing support for menu- and toolbar-actions. (Incuding support for some of the "Java Look and Feel Graphics Repository" actions.)

Look at the *.swing and the *.swing.action packages.

Just ask me if you don't find them.

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupid>org.softsmithy.lib</groupid>  
    <artifactid>lib-core</artifactid>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

API:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/index.html

If you have questions just ask me!

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, thanks. Does this also allow you to rotate components? I will look into this mor, but just to let you know your Demo's WebStart seems to be broken :(

Comment: Yes, I know, some access rights to files on the server. I haven't find time to fix this yet, but you can download the sample code.

Comment: Rotation is not supported currently, as far as I remember (I wrote it some years ago). But maybe you can write extensions or even provide a patch? The library is open source.

Comment: @rocky-triton I am going to be using this for a document editor, I just couldn't think of a better way to word it then "GUI Editor like". So maybe think more like Visio, Photoshop, Illustrator, or Publisher...

@Puce I might. This is a small part of a much larger application for me that is more of a "nice to have" than a critical component. I might have to put it on hold until I have more time, but I really do like your work there.